# docker-compose run scripts when container is initialized

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-workbench, docker-entrypoint

I am new to docker. I am on a windows 7 machine and using docker toolbox.
I am trying to write a docker-compose.yml for MySQL which creates a database and runs 2 scripts (create table and insert)

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-image:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myDatabase
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwtest
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
     - ./sqlscripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

volumes:
    sqlscripts:
```

I can connect to the database, but the problem I have is running the scripts.
mostly I run into the following error:

> mysql-image_1  | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line
>   interface can be insecure.
>
> mysql-image_1  | ERROR: Can't initialize
>   batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block
>   device. docker_mysql-image_1 exited with code 1

I searched for a while, trying to get it work but at this point I do not know what I am doing wrong. This is one of my .sql scripts which I am trying to run it when the docker container starts. 
createTablePerson.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `myDatabase`.`Person` (
  `idPerson` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPerson`));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated further and it seems is because I am on Windows 7 and I have to use docker-toolbox which runs in a VirtualBox VM. It seems that the location I had my scripts, is not shared between windows host and docker-toolbox. I noticed the files were copied in the container but they where considered as empty directories. I moved my scripts to user location and it seems the scripts are copied to the container and run perfectly. Now I am searching for a way to try make other paths visible. I prefer to have my scripts under my java project.